# Java : Random setSeed

Tags: java, random

I'm having a small conceptual problem.

I need to seed my random so that I always get the same radom when I reload my levels.

So therefore I need to use [`Random#setSeed`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#setSeed%28long%29).

The problem I have then is that I then need to do a

```
Random r = new Random();
r.setSeed(currentSeed);
```

The problem is that I have then have to pass/fetch this instance of `r` across my code.

I would like to know if there is solution close to C:

```
Math.Random(currentSeed);
```

The closest I have now is:

```
ClassA:
  public static Random r;
  private int currentSeed = ...;
  initRandom(){
    r = new Radom(currentSeed);
  }

ClassB:
  ...
  //instead of Math.random();
  r.random();
  ...
```

But that doesn't seem very nice.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to pass the same Random instance around, either as a parameter, or by mean of a global (static variable or singleton).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the same random across classes and you want reproduce-ability, you need to ensure that it is used in the same order as well. If your classes execute in a different order e.g. if its multi-threaded you will get a different result.

Comment: No multithread, reading from a xml and strored in a list so I always ge t the same order ^^